# FullCalendar Laravel Color Text for no fullday event

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, fullcalendar-5

Hi everyone i wand to change color of text for no full day event but still get white color

the circle one .

this is my code :

```
$eventsData = Event::all();
    $events = [];
$events[] = \Calendar::event(
            $row->name, //event title
            $row->allDay, //full day event?
            new Carbon($row->start_date), //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
            new Carbon($row->end_date), //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
            $row->id , //optionally, you can specify an event ID
            $options = [
           'backgroundColor'=> $color,
            'textColor' => '#000000',
                'eventColor'=>'#378006',
                'description' => 'hello',
                'eventClassNames' => 'fc-event-title fc-sticky text-success',
                'display'=> 'auto'

                ]
        );
```

the all day event has been changed but the item list no

and this is the calander option

```
$calendar = new Calendar();
    $calendar->addEvents($events)
        ->setOptions([
            'locale' => 'fr',
            'timeZone' => 'Africa/Tunis',
            'firstDay' => 1,
            'businessHours'=> true,
            'displayEventTime' => true,
            'displayEventEnd' => true,
            'selectable' => true,
            'themeSystem' => 'bootstrap',
            'progressiveEventRendering' => true,

            'editable'=> true,
            'selectHelper'=>true,
            'initialView' => 'dayGridMonth',
            'dragScroll' => true,
            'dropAccept'=> '.cool-event',
            'eventResizableFromStart'=> true,
            'dayMaxEvents'=> true,

            'headerToolbar' => [
                'end' => 'today prev,next dayGridMonth timeGridWeek timeGridDay'
            ]
        ]);
```

[image]

Comment: Hello any answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add styling inside head tag.

```
<style>
    .fc-title{
        color:white!important;
    }
</style>
```